# Will change from abstract class to sealed class break simple client use

Tags: c#

I'm changing a class from `public abstract AwesomeClass`, to `public sealed AwesomeClass`.  I've also added a new property.  All existing members are unchanged.  I know that this is a breaking change.  Clients that have implemented `AwesomeClass` or relied on it being abstract via reflection will be broken.

My question is, will clients that have only used members of instances of `AwesomeClass` that I've provided, be broken (and if yes how)?  *None of the clients will have a dependency on any of my types that implemented `AwesomeClass` as they were all internal*.  I think not, but...

Here is the class before and after:

```
public abstract class AwesomeClass
{
    public abstract Guid SuperGuid { get; set; }
    public abstract int SuperInt { get; set; }
}

public sealed class AwesomeClass
{
    public Guid SuperGuid { get; set; }
    public int SuperInt { get; set; }
    public int OtherSuperInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I *think* you're fine, but only because I cannot think of a counter-example at the moment...

Comment: So you're saying that the external API that you have supported is some form of factory/query facility that has always returned `AwesomeClass` objects?

Comment: My public API raised some events that contained a collection of `AwesomeClass` instances.  There was only one implementation, which was internal.

Comment: I think he's saying that all his instance classes inherit AwesomeClass which I presume contains some code reuse, so will this reuse still be available if he makes the class sealed, correct?

Comment: If your worried about breaking clients I'd publish a new end point and just mark this one as obsolete.

Comment: If you're relying on a factory to make the `AwesomeClass` then is there a downside to providing an `IAwesomeClass` interface instead of relying on the concrete type?

Comment: @asawyer I would normally do something like this, but have reasons not to (if possible).

Comment: @Romoku I have reasons for wanting to check this and leave as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that when you have this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
}

void UpdateFooBar(Foo foo)
{
    foo.Bar = "Updated";
}
```

And you change `abstract class Foo` to `sealed class Foo`, will `UpdateFooBar(Foo foo)` continue to work?

What kept you from trying? But yes, it will.

Comment: Good point if it breaks, a very quick test will show you immediately!

Comment: I've added the class change code to my question.  The members were all abstract in the first class.  Doubt this makes any difference, but it's different to your example.  I did try this in a sample, but wanted to double check.  Plus, better to have it public on SO no?

Comment: @codecaster I will accept your answer, but just wondered if there is any update based on my previous comment and updated question?

Comment: @bentayloruk as far as I can see, this change will not break anything given the constraints you mentioned (class not being inherited and all).